# How to find the equilibrium points of this dynamical system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

Consider the dynamical system

$$\dot x= cx - \frac{x}{1+x^{2}}$$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, with $c$ a positive constant.

Establish the location and number of equilibrium points of the system for all values of $c$. Then using linear stability analysis, determine the stability of the equilibrium points for all values of $c$.

My solution so far:

I set the RHS to $0$ and rearranged to get
 $$x(cx^2+(c-1))=0$$

so then $x=0$ or $cx^2+(c-1)=0$.

This second equation can be rearranged as $cx^2=1-c$

so when $c=1$ we have $x=0$, when $c\gt1$, we have no solutions.

But I am not sure what happens in the case $0\lt c \lt 1$.

Comment: just solve  the equation $cx^2=1-c$ for $x$...?

Comment: @LorenzoQuarisa yes, just realised how simple it is.

Comment: @Moo I am trying to analyse it using $c=\frac{1}{2}$ so then the equilibrium points are $x=0, -1, 1$. If you find the phase diagram for this, will this be the same as for all $0 \lt c \lt 1$?